# A No-EU student on Schengen Visa to travel UK

Tags: uk, schengen, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, stuttgart

I am a schengen study visa Holder, I wish to visit UK for tourism, am I allowed to apply for a UK tourist visa on being a German student visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can apply for a UK visa from any location where there is a visa processing centre. It does not have to be from your home country https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply